# Debugging (GAE) java 404 errors app routes

Tags: java, debugging, http-status-code-404

I have a Google App Engin webapp written in JAVA.
Routing should is done based on the settings in app.yaml which includes:

```
handlers:
- url: /testPage
  jsp: /testPage.jsp
```

When I tried to access /testPage I got a 404 error.
It turned out I have placed the JSP in a sub folder of /war instead of directly inside it.

What I want to know is if there is some way to get from JAVA/GAE a more detailed description of the 404 error saying where did it actually look for the file that it failed to find?

(I am working with eclipse 4.3.1 if that is relevant info)

Thanks